# Convert Gemtext to HTML

Tags: code-golf, string

[Gemtext](https://communitywiki.org/wiki/GemText) is a very simple markup format used by the alternative web protocol Gemini. Write a Gemtext to HTML converter.

From the Wiki:

> A line of text is a paragraph, to be wrapped by the client. It is is
> independent from the  lines coming before or after it.
>
> A list item starts with an asterisk and a space. Again, the rest of
> the line is the line item, to be wrapped by the client.
>
> A heading starts with one, two, or three number signs and a space. The
> rest of the line is the heading.
>
> A link is never an inline link like it is for HTML: it’s simply a line
> starting with an equal-sign and a greater-than sign: “=>”, a space, an
> URI, and some text. It could be formatted like a list item, or like a
> paragraph. Relative URIs are explicitly allowed.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> # This is a heading 
> This is the first paragraph.
> * a list item
> * another list item 
> This is the second paragraph.
> => http://example.org/ Absolute URI
> => //example.org/ No scheme URI
> => /robots.txt Just a path URI
> => GemText a page link
> ```

This should produce this HTML tree (just the equivalent tree, not the exact formatting):

**EDIT** you don't need the `<ul>` tags to produce valid HTML

```
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is the first paragraph.</p>
<li>a list item</li>
<li>another list item</li>
<p>This is the second paragraph.</p>
<a href="http://example.org/">Absolute URI</a>
<a href="//example.org/">No scheme URI</a>
<a href="/robots.txt">Just a path URI</a>
<a href="GemText">a page link</a>
```

All text must pass through. All of `<>"&` should be converted to HTML entities, even if they don't confuse browsers, to be safe

**EDIT**: For the sake of this question, you don't have to do 2nd and 3rd level headings

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! It is a reasonably well written challenge, but from next time, try to use [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedbaclk before posting, Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! For future reference, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main. We do also require challenges to have an objective winning criteria, so I've edited in "Shortest code wins" to be in line with the [code-golf] tag

Comment: Can links be nested inside list items, or list items within list items?  Generally, what kind of nesting is and isn't allowed among elements?

Comment: @Jonah afaik there's no nesting at all

Comment: Also, unrelated to the challenge but: were you at all aware of the Sandbox before posting this, or were mine and Wasif's comments the first you'd heard of it?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Hadn't heard of the sandbox. I'll remember that!

Comment: Are the only transformations the ones you specify? What about a line like `# A <h1> header`? Do we ignore any errors we might cause?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman that should end up as `<h1>A &lth1&gt header</h1>`. I'll edit the question to include that

Comment: OK, but note that everything about the transformation should be in question body - so if there are any other escape characters or edge cases you want handled, then you need to fully explain them. What you have there will only force people to escape `<>`, so you'd need to list each HTML escape, for example. If the question you want to ask is more like that, consider deleting for now and moving to the sandbox, as there are likely a lot of changes required to make it clear. But if you just want it to be a "lazy" conversion then feel free to leave it here.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I'll do that for now. I don't want to clutter the front page with an ambigous question

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I've moved it to the Sandbox, should I delete this question now?

Comment: I would recommend leaving this undeleted, as you can come back and edit in the updated version once it's done in the Sandbox

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Deleted questions can be easy to lose, especially for users with <10k and even more for users who aren't as familiar with the SE system. Closing this question would be a better response to prevent any answers, as that way, it's still findable and searchable, and it appears in the OPs profile in an obvious location. Plus, the OP would lose any reputation gained from this if it were deleted, and so would find it difficult to engage with Meta

Comment: We have an answer that works now so I think we could keep this open

Comment: The question requires "All of <>"& should be converted to HTML entities", but it also allow "produce this HTML tree (just the equivalent tree, not the exact formatting)". Only < and & followed by something may construct HTML entities are required to be converted to make the HTML tree work. For example, browsers won't get confused with `<p>3 > 2</p>`. So, must some answer escape all these characters? Or an answer is still valid as long as no injection may happened (as equivalent HTML tree)?

Comment: @tsh question edited - you must escape these characters anywhere for the sake of safety

Comment: @RHarrington if so, is `'` required to be escaped? HTML allow attribute use `'` instead of `"`, and `'` in attribute may be _unsafe_. For example if we generate `<a href='https://example.com/'hidden='>Click Me!</a>` by `=> https://example.com/'hidden= Click Me!`. The link will be hidden to user.

Comment: @tsh No. I would change the question but there are 4 answers now and they'd get invalidated. Now I know why to use the sandbox :|

Comment: This is really late, but can we assume that unless the line is a link, it will never start with `=`?

Comment: Also, can we escape even if there is no need? For example `a` becomes `&#97;`?

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-p`), 132 bytes

```perl
s,^((#)|(\*)|=> (\S+)|) *(.*?) *$,$t=$2?h1:$3?li:$4?a:p;"<$t".($4&&qq( href="$4")).">".($5=~s~[<>"&]~"&#".(ord$&).";"~ger)."</$t>",e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBBT8MgFMfv@xSEkYbW2UbtLt3axpPRgwc3T04Ttr0VYlsYvCU7LP3oVhqzTE1IgN/v/3iAAVtP@95NPjgfhye@isJTXhC@WlyFp5BEPI5KP7EJw5zdlvImY3dlrTKWliIzMzpnSGPO0iDY7zmRFnY5ZSkNw5gWg5jmneve5gUN3jsajD3SdssCr2e0q8D6xTxhWNAJ9P2YLKVyxA9BJIitaisyOiOUQHbKOiRGWFFZYWQ8inyyVp4phGbYtdrn7IX9rXew0e329wH@rRLRZEkCR9GYGmJtq4Tcr52uDwjk9eVxyPzTz5q4jYTm4q1ea3QxHpE8HXxv4ZugPOsHaJZw/KEV@Nu1n6PhT760QaVb11@bbw)

Another 132 bytes

```perl
s-^([#*]|=> (\S+)|) *(.*?) *$-"<".($t=(p,a,li,h1)[ord($1)%4]).($2&&qq( href="$2")).">".($3=~s~[<>"&]~"&#".(ord$&).";"~ger)."</$t>"-e
```

Comment: I was going to say you needed `ul` but it seems it'll be accepted without it! I'll change the question

Answer (score 3):

## Java + Android, <s>227</s> 206 bytes

```
l->l.map(s->android.text.Html.escapeHtml(s).replaceAll("^# (.*)","<h1>$1</h1>").replaceAll("^\\* (.*)","<li>$1</li>").replaceAll("^=&gt; (.*?) (.*)","<a href='$1'>$2</a>").replaceAll("^[^<].*","<p>$0</p>"))
```

Accepts a `Stream` of lines as input and returns a `Stream` of lines.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VVbb9s2FH7XrzhQAluyHdreS4tY1pB1zbYC3YC6feoFoCXKYkqJGknlgia/PTuUVEW@VOnrABNBTB5@5zu3z/QVvaZnV/HXR54VUhm4wjMpDRckKfPIcJmT0cLZu9RGMZrZq6JcCx5BJKjW8JbyHL45gKuxa0MNflxLHkOGt97KKJ5vPn4Gqjbar7F2fcipuvunYIoaqYJVxR/U4DCEZPkozkJBMlp4@iykeayQkRh2a8ifJhOE6YgWzG497RPFCkEjdiGE5345AY@MfHfiBuk8PJ0HU/xwdzCfPo1alOAVCj92UcvBxiws7le/RVNIFUuWw9P5MDz9JZjSPa@PX4LPZGSxRXg6C6YFIvzHRVv5dq0geM40LBszkYnnnsD7lGvAP4zGaIw4QL7vRpMySLjSBgqq6EbRIiV4PUK04GjlhmX1OZeIVU/WXRbNIpnH2zTLEFJjivPplN3SrBCMSLWZwsVaS1EaBh/e/VWjdgB/S9BRyrIuQsm1NJqYWwNvSsyBYiiTPgH@YNl7HGll3zDbiq/uBNxESjiBNVX2EBimDbbwqYEJoUUh7ryqcz5JpHpNo9Rb3WkskcjSnJ8X2Fsj8sbpwXlwptOLWkS1dJ1awI2wKg030q0vrNIaZW/ZreIOKr4eJ3R0@SqlasX@LVkesYrPh29dESD8t5KLGAeEOaMCcnazbfc6Rd9wk/J8Ze4E8xA@qRgnMKs3RLB8Y1LP73goZkqVW25iZM3rtQ2pClD8muJEu9/Zbpi9HCewV9OkDde3cBg2ikIGu2V53O0FDhA8a@fYhAq2wG1gYbgZj7tYuyJMAiLEVpXb04XxOJa2heIJeAhawjAY7jLYZfuCOsIgnjsQZtFVWNUjYEKzDk34PM3mJ2gGz9Pgt6qfJ1zC7Pb3l7MZDAbYiaA6Xl5eHmKuPQKLeFU7cBjDvO7vIYe2xfFui63fTlrdKHGTVxMm7s@r9RyPF06fcCIZs0LanaWbzWe44L5SjI/Fn31vRRDA/Okiri8wlx@zbzX9BN/x5tBGbC3u3jzauTj9lu25YUovXsP9vR0aDOF5KXSyagruyWlPa4cD3KRcMPA6MrDj2p90D8VenvlaFz/s0cERPzh9ldu4B4vr7Ve06@Ns7@wPQf3/@JofX/Pja358zY@v@f/6NX/8Dw)

*Saved 21 bytes thanks to [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236)*

### Explanation

```
l->l.map(
   s->android.text.Html.escapeHtml(s) //Escape line using Android utility class
   .replaceAll("^# (.*)","<h1>$1</h1>")
   //Match headers 
   .replaceAll("^\\* (.*)","<li>$1</li>")
   //Match list items
   .replaceAll("^=&gt; (.*?) (.*)","<a href='$1'>$2</a>")
   //Match links (> is &gt; after being escaped)
   .replaceAll("^[^<].*","<p>$0</p>")
   //If string does not start with <, then nothing has been replaced,
   //so enclose entire line in paragraph element
)
```

Comment: Clever, but fails for `foo # bar`. You should probably add `^` at the start of each regex. Also, you can probably gain a few bytes by calling like this: `l.map(s->{var x=android.text.Html.escapeHtml(s).replaceAll...; ... })`

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks for the help.

Comment: All in all, I could golf it to [211 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/26d3p37t).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks! That's a nice way to avoid the conditional.

Comment: A few more bytes can be gained if you remove the `{1,3}` from the first regex as it is not required to support multi-level headers, reducing to 206 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>104</s> 103 bytes

```
&
&amp;
"
&#34;
>
&gt;
<
&lt;
m`^
<p>
p>(#+)
h$.1>
p>\*
li>
p>=&gt; (\S+)
a href="$1">
<(\w+).*
$&</$1>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9BS8QwEIXv8yuGtoRuF1qKnmwb8CR68KDrrYjZ3dkm2DYhncX@@5oiy6owkHnvfZNJPLEZ1bIIEGpwFUQg4pvbCiSIjiuoQfThGD7eoXYSnEzj7QZ0kperaDPozdo0K4xp@xpChdrTqYmSMpJQp@3XdpNnkIi6SEq5LDHutJkwVABJHc3YIVws1oQn4ydGp7zqvHI6hyyQvQmeYRpWNdrA@av3d36igx2Pvy9oJGpmd1cUNIdP9pRb3xV4v59sf2bCt5fHlfkXP1ucDpqGa@7t3vKU88z4dA67VVjC@hI/0LCj@cftKLxu/IRaRuIb) Works with multiple headers. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @OlivierGrégoire. Explanation:

```
&
&amp;
"
&quot;
>
&gt;
<
&lt;
```

HTML encode everything.

```
m`^
<p>
```

Assume each line is a paragraph.

```
p>(#+)
h$.1>
p>\*
li>
p>=&gt; (\S+)
a href="$1">
```

Fix up headings, lists and links.

```
<(\w+).*
$&</$1>
```

Add closing tags.

Comment: Could `&quot;` be replaced with `&#34;`?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Nice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 160 bytes

```
s!&!&amp;!g
s!<!\&lt;!g
s!>!\&gt;!g
s!"!\&#34;!g
ta
:a
s!^*\(.*\)!<li>\1</li>!
s!^#\(.*\)!<h1>\1</h1>!
s!=&gt; \([^ ]*\)\(.*\)!<a href="\1">\2</a>!
t
i<p>
a</p>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDBasMwEETv@oqVAybNwSZtT6ks0lNpDy2U9FQ3sIk3lqltGUkB/326SmJSEGj0ZjRa5Kk6nbxMZYrd8CRr4aWSZdqGi9as66tOWM8eHuMhoFgho@2inGeL8k6qttHlUuW8ychnEzfLM@ct8iKWQTn/3sIP21MIwTg6FEm5THR5r3LkcBCNGrRAlQ/6dJrBxjQeeHGWsGr6GhBRKKWEFqlIxOQHQ3BonA8woMPa4WCymFzwzbZh3ATqrqC3nHY3fK78X@Rpb/vq1gQpoz5QvyeQOhOFBhPCsMpzGvn/Wsqsq3N43nnbHgPB1@drzFxtNfnvFvzeUHcLOLuzwWdhDPB25GmQ3wwm2kqvP9bJOo2xF@o2NF7cmnju/jfiURTgjT22FezobDoUxQgeO/oD)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>243 215 210 194 193</s> 191 bytes

```javascript
n=>n.split`
`.map(e=>`<${t={'#':'h1','*':'li','=>':'a'}[(s=e.split` `)[0]]||'p'}${a=t<'b'?` href="${s[1]}"`:''}>${s.slice(2-!a).join` `.replace(/./g,c=>`&#${Buffer(c)[0]};`)}</${t}>`).join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBNT@swELznVyy0wgkC58Gx1EHvXRAcOCDeqapkN93EBie2bBdVCvntZcOHEEg@zM7Ozo73Sb2oWAfj03nvtnhoxKEXVc@jtybJTPJO@RxFJZfzIYmBzdiC6Qt2xk4JWENAVIQUG1d5FPg5B7JY/VmvX1@ZZ@N8UCIt2YZdS9ABG3E8H@LqYj0eywVjY0UVj9bUmF@eH6mCPznTkwMP6K0ituRle1ZThJPZfPi3axoMeT35j1eyGJclBRsr@TmXyUPt@pigpt@AADmDR20i0FOgUW1N30L2RSWN0JhAcq@CaoPymmenpLSGOJOwm6rekS58cz/nI9LC7bcBnMDGKvIRFeiU/KIsca86b5G70JbwdxOd3SWE/w@3k@ZX@95BrDV2732oAN81wW1cijztE9ztKIaifUl/Wdxg94j7D7ZFCto/y2w6gyNX69q8yadzFMXV4Q0)

As with most of my longer answers, I will golf this gradually.

Produces unreadable HTML, but still containing the same text. If this is disallowed, let me know and I will roll it back.

*-16 bytes thanks to @A Username*

Comment: [229](https://tio.run/##XVDBbtswDL37K9g0iOyuk5drGnnYqWgPOwzdyTAgxWEstbKlSUoRwPW3Z3TXolgBQSIfHx8f9aieVWyD8enr4PZ4PojzIKqBR29NkpnkvfI5ikpul2MSI7tkG6bX7JpdUWANBaKiSLGpzqPAtz6QRf2taV5emGfTclQibdmOfZegAx7EYjnGet1MC7lhbKoo49GaFvP1l4sLVfBHZwaS4AG9VQSX9bZarJqyu27JyGo51swmmtzN15@jmx/Ve9bUbCYyHlGFVudt0Uw3spi2JXmfKvmmnMlz64aYoKWFQYC8hAdtItBRoFHtzdBB9g4ljXAwgeheBdUF5TXProhpDWEmYT9ngyNe@MD@749IA/cfArCCnVWkIyrQKflNWeKJNrDIXehK@LGLzh4Twu9fdzPnU/mng9hq7F/rUAG@coLbuRR5OiW4P5INRfOSfpe4xf4BT//QDsno8CSz@RscqVrX5Yd8/o6iuDn/BQ) with the readable HTML, this can be used to golf waht you have.

Comment: @Ausername Thanks! Your suggestions are helpful. Would it be possible to keep the unreadable HTML while still using your tips? This would golf down even further

Comment: [yep, 194](https://tio.run/##XVDLTsMwELznK5a2wgkPh17bOghxQHDggOBUVbKbbmODE1u2QZVCvr1seQiBtIfd2ZnZ0T6rNxXrYHw679wG91ux70TV8eitSTKTvFU@R1HJxaRPomdjNmN6ys7YCTXWUCMq6hQblnkU@K0DWSwvVqv3d@bZMOmVSAu2ZpcSdMCtGE36uJyuhpGcMTZUNPFoTY359PToSBX82ZmOLHhAbxXBJS@bs5oyHI8nfc1rrcI1Zb1KeTHMZTEsSso2VPJbmcl97bqYoCYSCJBjeNQmApUCjWpjugayHyhphK0JRPcqqCYor3l2QkxrCDMJ28PUOeKFX@yvPiId3PwawDGsrSIfUYFOyc/KEneq9Ra5C00JV@vo7GtCeHq4PXD@re8dxFpj@7mHCvCTE9zapcjTLsHdK8VQdC/pH4sbbB9x94U2SEG7F5kd3uDI1bom3@aHdxTFfP8B)

Answer (score 0):

## AWK, 171 bytes

```
awk '{if($1=="#"){$1="<h1>";$0=$0"</h1>"}else if($1=="*"){$1="<li>";$0=$0"</li>"}else if($1=="=>"){$1="<a href=\""$2"\">";$0=$0"</a>"}else{$1="<p>";$0=$0"</p>"}{print$0}}'
```

I'm learning AWK so probably can be done better.
Bugs:

- There are spaces after the opening tags
- Doesn't remove the URL (I've tried doing `$2=""`, but it breaks the lines)